# Game starts countdown by server time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i have a game and when a player clicks play button a countdown starts and game begins when count hits zero,Problem is it counts from the Os/Computer time and their is a difference in secconds from computer to computer causing players to start at differnt times.

Is it possible to have the countdown count down by server time to keep players in sync so everyone starts at the same time?

Code is writen in actionscript3.0 and Flash cs5.5
the code provided currently counts down by remaining Os sec's of the current min so if theirs 30 sec left in the current min it countsdown 30 sec
time1 in my database is 60 for 60 sec between games.
Any help would be more than apreciated
thanks in advance
dave

```
var timer4:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer4.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick4);
timer4.start();
function tick4(e:TimerEvent):void{
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("timerma2.php");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandlert);

loader.load(request);
function completeHandlert(e:Event) {
var time1 = e.target.data.time1;
var pattern = e.target.data.pattern;
var frames = e.target.data.frames;

var currentYear:Number = new Date().fullYear;
var targetDate:Date = new Date(currentYear, 11, 50);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(e:Event):void{

    var now:Date = new Date();

var timeLeft:Number = targetDate.getTime() - now.getTime();

var sec:Number = Math.floor(timeLeft/1000);
var min:Number = Math.floor(sec/60);


sec = sec % 60;
min = min % time1;

mintxt.text = (min < 10) ? "0"+min.toString() : min.toString();
sectxt.text = (sec < 10) ? "0"+sec.toString() : sec.toString();

 if (min == 0 && sec == 0){
     theframe();

     function theframe(){


         if (frames == 4){

    gotoAndStop (4); 


      timer4.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick4);
     removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loop);


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to all everything in sync would be to connect your game to your server using sockets, and have it pass the countdown to all connected players...

Comment: That's the only _correct_ way to solve this problem, given the premises noted in the question. The request to some server-side-sollution (ie.: PHP) would take more than a second, so you end up with estimating time left. The only way that really sync users is connecting them via sockets to the master server.